# wc -l in multiple file or directories

Tags: command-line

in current directory, there are some RunId from an experiment, is there any command to count number of RunId's separately at once. I am using now the following for each one of the RunId for the current directory: ls | grep RunId | wc -l

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Do you want to count the lines *in* a number of files as your question suggests? Or do you want to count the number of files containing "RunId" as per your example?

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply, in current directory, i have various runid from an experiment, i want to count the number of each runid in current directory. but by the above command i can count only one runid in the directory. for counting another runid i should manually type another script.

Comment: So, just to confirm: You have multiple directories, in which may or may not be a file named "RunId". And you want to count how many directory actually do have this file?

Comment: Dear Adaephon, your sentence is correct thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The command you ran would tell you the # of files containing RunId in the name in the current directory, say I wanted to do that in subdirectories as well I could do:

```
find . -type f -iname "*RunId*" | wc -l
```

or

```
find . -type f -exec basename | grep -c "RunId"
```

Edit based on further explanation of question:
If there are multiple files containing RunId## in their name you could get the counts of each by

```
find . -iname "*RunId*" | grep -o -E "RunId[0-9]*" | sort | uniq -c | sort --stable -n -r
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply, in current directory, i have various runid from an experiment, i want to count the number of each runid. but by command ls | grep runId | wc -l i can count only one runid in the directory at a time. for counting another runid i should manually type another script. but i want count of runid's separated by commas